# Generate file JSON from PHP script

Tags: php, arrays, json, php-7

How can I generate this structure file JSON from PHP script?

Example JSON:

```html
{
   "messages":[
      {
         "attachment":{
            "type":"image",
            "payload":{
               "url":"#"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: At least make some efforts and read how php can work with json.

Comment: a google of: "json php" and the top result is an example of `json_encode()`

Answer (score 1):

That should work.

```
$a = ["messages" => [["attachment" => ["type" => "image", "payload" => ["url" => "#"]]]]];
$b = json_encode ($a);
```